# Errno 11001 getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, api

I have this simple code from a tutorial

```
import requests

request = requests.get('https://api.github.com')
print(request.status_code)
```

Trying to run it leads to this error

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 
x000001E7939BE408>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

There is not much code, so I dont really know what I could have done wrong compared to the tutorial.

Comment: Can you ping api.github.com? Can you ping 140.82.118.6 (which is the address it resolves to for me)?

Comment: I dont know if I "pinged" it correctly but I used this ```os.system("ping 140.82.118.6")```  and then the cmd opened with 3 messages which all loosely translated said "Exceeded time for request" and the output was a "1". If I put the adress in my browser, I get this message: We didn't receive a proper request from your browser. Please contact us if the problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried to ping api.github.com?
Have you tried to access api.github.com from browser instead?

Comment: Im not quite sure what pinging means. I tried "pinging" it with the above command and got the result above. I can access api.github.com from my browser, but not 140.82.118.6.

Comment: I tried pinging it in cmd also with the ```ping 140.82.118.6``` and got the same result like in above comment.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping - run that from an LXTerminal window.

Comment: Hello Dougie, I have windows 10 as my operating system. I couldnt start this LXTerminal after some tries. Maybe Im just brain lagging. Is there another way to see what is wrong or should I try again to run it from this LXTerminal?

Comment: Ok the problem seems to be my network at work. I tried to ping it at home and it worked. Thank you all.